# Polymer build appears to exclude files in fragments

Tags: polymer

I notice my files in `polymer.json/fragments` are not copied over to my `build/bundled` folder. This causes 404 errors, how can I resolve this?

Strangely they are copied for the unbundled folder ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is usually because there is some error in `polymer.json`. For example, when trying to include a file that does not exist. Unfortunately, Polymer does not fail with an error; it succeed with weird results ...